# how are the array's temp storage used for delete recovery in C++?

Tags: c++, decoding

There is a comment in this source code that indicates that 
`/* phone_tmp & room_tmp array's are temp storage used for delete recovery */` but I honestly fail to see how this is an array, or pointer like I don't understand the structure of the code either. Can someone please explain it to ?

```
/* Globe variables */

int i; /*globe index*/

long int phone[MAXDB+1];

int room[MAXDB+1];

/* phone_tmp & room_tmp array's are temp storage used for delete recovery */

long int phone_tmp[MAXDB+1];

int room_tmp[MAXDB+1];

void AddEntry(int, long int);
```

Comment: Do you think that comment is the supposed array? Or are you confused about how the line: `long int phone_tmp[MAXDB+1];` is an array? This is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the following line of code

```
type name[size];
```

declares an array called `name` of length `size` where each element is an object of type `type`.

So `long int phone_tmp[MAXDB+1];` declares an array of `MAXDB+1` instances of `long int` named `phone_tmp`.

As far as delete recovery goes, the `delete` here is not any property of the language, but a feature specific to the program being coded.

Assuming your code comes from the following old C book:

[see-here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=3fZa9af1KtYC&pg=PA464&lpg=PA464&dq=%22temp%20storage%20used%20for%20delete%20recovery%22&source=bl&ots=yF4-bweW7-&sig=U7TOPRzE-kv7qGj_xAq7qHlU0sg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR-9S3qc7VAhXD5CYKHd1hDbMQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=%22temp%20storage%20used%20for%20delete%20recovery%22&f=false)

These arrays are used to allow users to "undo" delete operations.

Comment: The thing is tho, how many elements those this [ MAXDB+1]  represents ?

Comment: It represents `MAXDB+1` elements. You need to find where `MAXDB` is defined. Alternatively, you could use `sizeof(phone_tmp) / sizeof(phone_tmp[0])` to determine the array size if `MAXDB` is hard to track down.

Comment: Thank you frank, yea I'm trying to understand this old public source code and yea I looked up "MAXDB+1" element